# Count cells if two criteria - but sumproduct didnt work (Excel

Tags: excel

I need help with this, please:

I have a table with lot of data and I need count rows where is specific name and specific time (for example John 7:15, Tom 7:00, Nick 8:00 and I need know how many times in table is John beetven 7:00-08:00 and so on...)

countif(s), sumproducts didnt working for me :(

Thanks

Comment: Are the names and times in two different columns or the same column?

Comment: Names and times are in different columns...I try to write some VBA, but I dont know, how I can write "do count" :/

Comment: Which COUNTIF formula did you try?

Comment: Criteria A1 and B1 -> =countif (D1:C10;A1:B1)

Comment: Ah, you are misunderstanding how COUNTIF() works. Attempting an answer now.

Comment: aha, countif didnt work - error message "...too much criteria", countifs...just count by first criteria (or "value" error)

Comment: Answer tested and posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create extra columns, then you may want to try this.  I assume the times may have minutes, so that you may have "nick" in cell C2 and "8:15" in cell D2.  You want to know how many Nicks there are between 8 and 9?  Then in cell E2, extract the hour from the time with "=HOUR(D2)".

Then use COUNTIFS to handle multiple criteria.  Let's say you put "Nick" in cell A1 and the number 8 in cell A2, for 8am.  Then in cell A3 you could write "=COUNTIFS(C2:C5,A1,E2:E5,A2)" .

I like countifs (with an s) better than countif because it handles multiple criteria better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes! it is working also with date before time! I am so happy, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, select your entire times Column and make sure it is all in hh:mm:ss (hours, minutes, seconds) format.

In Column C, set up a Countifs function, with:

- The first criteria range being Column A (names)
- The first criteria being the name you are looking for, in quotes
- The second criteria range being Column B (times)
- The second criteria being ">(insert minimum hh:mm:ss value here)"
- The third criteria range being Column B (times)
- The third criteria being "<(insert maximum hh:mm:ss value here)"

Answer (score 0):

**Column A:**
John
John
John
John
John
Tom
Nick
Nick
Nick
Nick
Nick
Nick
Nick
Tom
Tom

**Column B:**
7:15
8:15
9:15
7:15
7:15
7:00
8:00
9:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
7:00
8:00

**Formula in C2  cell:**

=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)

**Formula in D2 cell**:

=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)